# proxy for distributed file share system in window

Tags: proxy, distributed-system, windows-share

Our application is deployed in a cluster environment,we have five servers(nodes) to serve the appliation.

And the datasource is not database but share file system in windows. We have two file servers.

We config the required file/folder shared name in the web.config in each node.

This is the [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65J4f.png).

As shown,now we only support single file server. And we have a copy for all the data in another server,how to use both of them?

I wonder if there is any proxy like nginx in http ( distributing request to different backend)? We config the proxy share directory in each web.config:

```
\\proxy\data
```

Then the `proxy` will redirect the request to different `file server`.

And solution?

Comment: You mean "how to implement [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29) ourselves" or something else?

Comment: I have google something about dfs,but it seems that the dfs in wndow just put all the shared files togther. It can not disstribute the request.